# Unknown column in 'on clause' after MySQL upgrade

Tags: mysql

I've been updating some old code which used PHP4 and MySQL 4.1 up to MySQL 5.6 / MariaDB 10. I've had a few issues with SQL JOINs
 and precedence but this one has really stumped me and is giving me the error  -

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'grouping_id' in 'on clause'
```

I've tried messing about with the order of the JOIN statements in the query below but I haven't had any success yet, as mentioned this query worked fine on MySQL 4.

```
SELECT
    team.team_id,
    team.team_name,
    competition.rel_sport_id,
    country.country_name
FROM
    team
LEFT JOIN team_grouping ON(
        rel_team_id = team_id AND team_grouping.rel_grouping_id = grouping_id
    )
LEFT JOIN grouping ON grouping_id = team_grouping.rel_grouping_id
LEFT JOIN country ON team.rel_country_id = country_id
LEFT JOIN sport ON team.rel_sport_id = sport_id
LEFT JOIN competition_country ON(
        rel_competition_id = competition_id AND competition_country.rel_country_id = country_id
    )
LEFT JOIN competition ON competition_id = '985'
WHERE
    team.rel_country_id = competition_country.rel_country_id AND team.rel_sport_id = competition.rel_sport_id AND grouping_id = '3'
ORDER BY
    team_name
```

Can anyone help with what could be wrong with the above query?

EDIT - Added table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `grouping` (
 `grouping_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `grouping_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`grouping_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin

CREATE TABLE `team` (
 `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `team_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `image` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rel_country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rel_sport_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`team_id`),
 KEY `IDX_team_1` (`rel_country_id`),
 KEY `IDX_team_2` (`rel_sport_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11918 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `country` (
 `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `country_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `image` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rel_geographic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`),
 KEY `IDX_country_2` (`rel_geographic_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=237 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `competition` (
 `competition_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `competition_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rel_sport_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rel_grouping_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rel_competition_tz_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
 `modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`competition_id`),
 KEY `IDX_competition_1` (`rel_sport_id`),
 KEY `IDX_competition_2` (`rel_grouping_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1133 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `sport` (
 `sport_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sport_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `image` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`sport_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `competition_country` (
 `rel_competition_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `rel_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`rel_competition_id`,`rel_country_id`),
 KEY `IDX_competition_country_1` (`rel_competition_id`),
 KEY `IDX_competition_country_2` (`rel_country_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: `grouping_id` is ambiguous, you should specify the table/alias `team.grouping_id` or `grouping.grouping_id`, etc But looks like your `JOIN` for `team_grouping`, should be after `JOIN grouping` Please include the SCHEMA for the tables in your question. `SHOW CREATE TABLE grouping`, etc

Comment: @fyrye thanks I've added the schema in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names in an `ON` clause can only refer to tables preceding it in the query. When you're joining through a relationship table, the first `ON` clause just relates with the table before it, you relate to the second table in the next `ON` clause.

So the `ON` clause for `team_grouping` should only have `rel_team_id = team_id`, and the `ON` clause for `competition_country` should only have `rel_country_id = country_id`.

I don't think you need the `WHERE` clause at the end. Those relationships should be implied already by the earlier joins. And since you're doing a `LEFT JOIN` with `grouping`, you should put restrictions on that table in the `ON` clause; otherwise, the null values from non-matching rows will be filtered out by the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
    team.team_id,
    team.team_name,
    competition.rel_sport_id,
    country.country_name
FROM team
LEFT JOIN team_grouping ON rel_team_id = team_id
LEFT JOIN grouping ON grouping_id = team_grouping.rel_grouping_id AND grouping_id = 3
LEFT JOIN country ON team.rel_country_id = country_id
LEFT JOIN sport ON team.rel_sport_id = sport_id
LEFT JOIN competition_country ON competition_country.rel_country_id = country_id
LEFT JOIN competition ON competition_id = '985' AND competition_id = competition_country.rel_competition_id
ORDER BY team_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to get the database returning the result I need using the following query after adding the WHERE clause back into your answer.

Comment: @stecooper Since `LEFT JOIN` would return `NULL` for records which do not match the `ON` condition, if the intent is to limit the recordset to those that only match the criteria, you would want to use an `INNER JOIN` as opposed to `LEFT JOIN`.